# Add syscalls to linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm new in working with kernel.
I want to add a linked list to my kernel, and I try to fix it like this link : [Linux Kernel Programming–Linked List](http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/28/linux-kernel-programminglinked-list/)

here is code's that I added to sys.c :

syscall defenition:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(init_process_list,pid_t,ppid)
{
 LIST_HEAD(processList);
 struct scallNode* newNode;
 newNode = kmalloc(sizeof(*newNode), GFP_KERNEL);
 newNode->ID = ppid;
 INIT_LIST_HEAD(&newNode -> list);
 list_add_tail(&newNode -> list , &processList.list);
 printk(KERN_INFO "INIT PROCESS UID: %u\n", ppid);
 return 0; 
}
```

and my struct for linked list:

```
struct scallNode{
    int ID;
    struct file_struct ffs;
    struct task_struct ts;
    struct list_head list;
};
struct scallNode processList;
```

and when I compile the kernel, I saw this error:

```
error: ‘struct list_head’ has no member named ‘list’   list_add_tail(&newNode -> list , &processList.list);
```

thanks for your replies.

that error disappeared, but another one is still exist.

```
kernel/sys.c:2136:24: error: field ‘fs’ has incomplete type      struct file_struct fs;
```

again thanks for your replies.

Comment: try just `processList` there is no `list` into `processList`

Comment: thanks man! it's work.

Comment: As problem about incomplete type `struct file_struct` isn't related with problem about correct `list_add_tail()` invocation, it is better to ask about these problems in **different question posts**. Stack Overflow is Question/Answer site, its format doesn't suited for unrelated questions in a single post. Before creating new question post about `struct file_struct`, make sure that you have searched enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list_add_tail`  function is

```
void list_add_tail(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head);
```

The second param should a pointer to a `struct list_head` so just use like this:

```
list_add_tail(&newNode -> list , &processList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did any kernel programming. But as per my knowledge below memory allocation is not correct:-

```
newNode = kmalloc(sizeof(*newNode), GFP_KERNEL);
```

I think it should be like:-

```
newNode = (struct scallNode *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct scallNode), GFP_KERNEL);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally answer finded.

in `list_add_tail(&newNode -> list , &processList.list);`
, `&processList`  most be use instead of `&processList.list` .

list_add_tail find list of processList itself.